# how to Pass command line argument ( baseURL) using java for selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have created a runnable jar for my Selenium webDriver suite. now i have to test this in multiple base URL,As the baseURl will change according to the need.
Can somebody please guide me through this. Is it possible to send command line arguments to Selenium Web Driver `driver.get(baseUrl)`

This code i have written but doesn't work.

```
public class news {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        try{
              JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
              js.executeScript("var pr=prompt('Enter your URL please:',''); alert(pr);");  
              Thread.sleep(15000L);
              String URL = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
              driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
              System.out.println(URL);
              driver.get(URL);
              System.out.println(URL);
            }catch(Throwable e)
              {
              System.out.println("failed");
            }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-target='#login-box']"));
        login.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("uname_h")).sendKeys("Abc@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password_h")).sendKeys("XYZ");
        WebElement login_button=driver.findElement(By.id("health_btn"));
        login_button.click();
       // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.className("glyphicon-publish-news-events")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[26]/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("newstitle")).sendKeys("Automation testing news");
        driver.findElement(By.id("newsdetails")).sendKeys("Automation testing news datails");
        WebElement webElement13 = driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_autogen3"));
        webElement13.sendKeys("ganesh");
        webElement13.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
}
```

Comment: try this java -jar jar-file-name.jar parameter-1 parameter-1

Comment: If you are testing this code with multiple url's please make sure that all elements in all the URL's will have the same locators. Otherwise this code won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below code:-

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //  prompt for the URL
    System.out.print("Enter your URL: ");

    // get their input as a String
    String URL = scanner.next();
```

Now url will be asked in terminal

Now pass this URL variable in you below line code:-

```
  driver.get(URL);
```

My below working code:-

```
  WebDriver driver=null;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //  prompt for the URL
    System.out.print("Enter your URL: ");

    // get their input as a String
    String URL = scanner.next();



    System.out.println( URL );
    final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get(URL);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks,URL was asked in terminal but its not get redirect to  that URL.

Comment: means it is not passing into URL. you need to press enter two times .. one after url enter and then hit again enter

Comment: After entering url in terminal i entered but then  it shows me error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[data-target='#login-box']"}

Comment: It say that not found login box because its not redirect to url.

Comment: This error basically occur when selenium is not able to locate any element for that he must be able to land on URL. can you try different URL .. can you try https://www.google.co.in .. if browser open with google then there must a any other issue

Comment: hey you have to use    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS); code first

Comment: In your code you are trying to locate element first and then you are using implicit wait .. that is the reason you are getting error

Comment: I put your above working code in my code it gives me error like "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Target URL 192.0.168.100 is not well-formed."

Comment: try to put it as "http://192.0.168.100/" .. use https instead of http if your domain is having https

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/157n83cxw1/using-relative-path-in-navigate-to-get

Comment: http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/Should-WebDriver-get-accept-relative-URLs-td21662.html

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.